# How can I find the probability of a dart landing in region S?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, multivariable-calculus

Someone plays darts that has a join density function based on the surface z = 6 - r where z is the likelihood of the dart landing at $(r,\theta)$. How can I find the value of C so that f is a joint density function and then find the probability that the thrown dart lands in S.

$$f(r,\theta)=
\begin{cases}
C_{1}(6-r), & \text{if} (r,\theta)∈ R\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Where R is the region inside of r = 2+4cosθ (which includes the little loop) and S is just the region inside the inner loop.

Right now I am thinking this might be how to solve for C if that's correct how would I actually find the probability?

[image]

Here is your integral

[image]

Comment: Not sure how you got those $\theta$ limits. Trying graphing on desmos.com, I find that $\frac{-2\pi}{3}$ to $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ seems to cover the larger shape and contents.  Oh, I see now, it was hard to read your limits. Still, try it with mine, see how it compares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation of $C_1$ is correct, although most people would have chosen the limits $-2\pi/3 \le \theta \le 2\pi/3$.  Yours is simply $2\pi$ added to this.  The exact value is $$C_1 = \left(12 \sqrt{3} + \frac{208\pi}{9}\right)^{-1}.$$

To get the desired probability, we have to integrate for the inner lobe, i.e. $$2 \int_{\theta = 2\pi/3}^\pi \int_{r=0}^{|2 + 4 \cos \theta|} C_1 (6-r)r \, dr \, d\theta.$$  Note the use of $2$ (to exploit symmetry) and the absolute value on the upper limit of $r$ because for $2\pi/3 < \theta \le \pi$, we have $r(\theta) < 0$.  I get $$\frac{82\pi - 135\sqrt{3}}{52\pi + 27\sqrt{3}}.$$

---

Since there is interest in the actual computation of the integral for the inner lobe, I will provide an **outline**.  You should be able to fill in the gaps using various elementary trigonometric identities.  Note that on $\theta \in [2\pi/3, \pi]$, $r \le 0$, thus $(6-|r|)r = (6+r)r$, and

$$\begin{align}
2C_1 \int_{\theta = 2\pi/3}^\pi \int_{r=0}^{2 + 4 \cos \theta} (6+r)r \, dr \, d\theta
&= 2C_1 \int_{\theta = 2\pi/3}^\pi \left[3r^2 + \frac{r^3}{3}\right]_{r=0}^{2 + 4 \cos \theta} \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{8C_1}{3} \int_{\theta = 2\pi/3}^\pi  (1 + 2 \cos \theta)^2 (11 + 4 \cos \theta) \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{8C_1}{3} \int_{\theta = 2\pi/3}^\pi 41 + 60 \cos \theta + 30 \cos 2\theta + 4 \cos 3\theta \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{8C_1}{3} \left[ 41\theta + 60 \sin \theta + 15 \sin 2\theta + \frac{4}{3} \sin 3\theta \right]_{\theta=2\pi/3}^\pi.
\end{align}$$
The rest is obvious.

Comment: Why is your upper limit $|2+4\cos(\theta)|$? The polar region $$0<r<|2+4\cos(\theta)|$$ $$2\pi/3<\theta<4\pi/3$$ resides in the left half plane $\{(x,y):x<0\}$ and is not contained in the support of $f$. See here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yhuy4vyfrq

Comment: @MatthewPilling Because the integrand $(6-r)r$ is **negative** when $r < 0$, which occurs when $2\pi/3 < \theta < 4\pi/3$.  You are thinking geometrically when the computation no longer requires you to do so.  All you need to do is set up the integral of the density on the inner lobe $S$, but you are forgetting that this lobe is being traversed over a negative $r$.

Comment: Another way to understand this is that when we found $C_1$ by integrating over the outer lobe $R$, we always had $r \ge 0$, but $S$ is contained in $R$, so if you allow $r < 0$ when integrating only inside $S$, you are basically using a different value of the likelihood for the same region.

Comment: I'll think about it... It just appears as of your finding the volume underneath the surface $$z=6-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ over a region that isn't contained in $R$ at all, which is troubling. The bounds on your polar integral are certainly describing a region in the left half plane.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Would it satisfy you if I wrote instead $$2 \int_{\theta = 2\pi/3}^{\pi} \int_{r = 0}^{2 + 4 \cos \theta} (6 - |r|)r \, dr \, d\theta?$$  Surely you cannot object to the limits of integration in this case.  And you cannot object to using $6 - |r|$ as the likelihood because this is also required if you want the likelihood to be consistent between $R$ and $S$.  You will find that this integral has the *same* value as the one I wrote.

Comment: To be absolutely clear, here is a numeric example.  When finding $C_1$, we integrated over $R$, which includes the point $(r, \theta) = (2, 0)$ since when $\theta = 0$ we have $0 \le r \le 6$.  The likelihood at this point is $6-r = 4$.  But when we integrate over $S$ with $2\pi/3 < \theta < 4\pi/3$, this includes $\theta = \pi$, and $(r, \theta) = (-2, \pi)$.  **But this is the same point** as $(2,0)$, yet the likelihood would be $6 - r = 8$.  You cannot do this.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much.

Comment: Hold why does your decimal approximation come out to 0.113 but when I calculate it I am getting 0.166???

Comment: If I plug in your integral I am not getting your answer so something must be up here.

Comment: Check my post I added your integral and you can see that desmos is getting another answer and normally desmos is correct.

Comment: @UnSure what you entered into Desmos is not what I wrote.  You are calculating the integral without the absolute value.

Comment: oh ok why do I need the absolute value because I have never used that in the past for these questions

Comment: @UnSure I literally explained all of this in the comments above as well as in the answer.